# Azure Synapse: Connect to Apache spark pool using a local Python script

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am working with Azure Synapse. Here, I can create a notebook, select one of the Apache Spark Pools and execute the following code:

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM DataBaseName")
df.show(10)
```

I have the use-case where I need to be able execute code from a local Python script. How do I create a connection with a specific pool, push the code to the pool for execution and if applicable get the results?

As my local editor I am using Spyder.

Comment: have u checked the necessary credentials and permissions to access the Spark pool from your local machine